# React Native iOS webview how to load local html by uri

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, webview, react-native-ios

I am trying to run local html file in webview, but it doesn't load full content.
I tested it on Native app with same html file and it shows well.

I am not sure what is problem.

**Native code**

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.uiDelegate = self;
        mapView.navigationDelegate = self;
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!
        mapView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        mapView.load(request)
    }
```

**React Native code**

```
<WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          onLoad={this.onLoad}
          source={Platform.OS === 'android' ? { uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' } : require('../ios/web/index.html')}
          dataDetectorTypes={'none'}
          ref='webview'
          onMessage={e => this.onMessage(JSON.parse(e.nativeEvent.data))}
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
          injectedJavaScript={patchPostMessageJsCode}
          useWebKit={true}
          />
```

**React Native screenshot**

[image]

**Native screenshot**

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

try resize the webview so,

```
import{Dimensions, SafeAreaView, WebView} from 'react-native';

<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>

     <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          onLoad={this.onLoad}
          source={Platform.OS === 'android' ? { uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' } : require('../ios/web/index.html')}
          dataDetectorTypes={'none'}
          ref='webview'
          onMessage={e => this.onMessage(JSON.parse(e.nativeEvent.data))}
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
          injectedJavaScript={patchPostMessageJsCode}
          useWebKit={true}
          style={{ height: Dimensions.get('window').width.height, width:Dimensions.get('window') , resizeMode: 'cover', flex: 1 }}
          />

</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: thank for reply. do you think resizing webview can be the solution?

Comment: i'm not fairly sure. the content still doesnt fully load even after you resize it?